# How to ensure file has been written to disk before reading it

Tags: python, subprocess, read-write

I want to read a `plan.txt` file generated by the [fast-downward](https://www.fast-downward.org/) planner, to do so I'm using `subprocess` as follows:

```py
import subprocess

search_options = "lama-first"
## Call Planner
cmd = [
    "python3",
    self.planner_path,
    "--alias",
    search_options,
    "--plan-file",
    self.plan_path,
    self.domain_path,
    self.problem_path,
]
## Read plan.txt
cmd2 = ["cat", self.plan_path]
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

plan = []
try:
    # Huge dealy to be sure that the plan is written to the txt file
    time.sleep(1)
    result2 = subprocess.run(cmd2, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    plan = result2.stdout.decode("utf-8")
except:
    pass
```

Can you please tell me what is the best approach to be sure that the plan was written to disk before trying to read it, rather than adding huge time delay? thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `except: pass`. It hides all exceptions, so you won't be notified about relevant errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to call `time.sleep(...)`, because (1)  `subprocess.run` waits for the subprocess to exit; (2) the libc and the kernel together make sure that all pending data is flushed to the output files when the (sub)process exits.

The modified code looks like this:

```py
import os
import subprocess

try:
    # Remove output of previous invocation.
    os.remove(self.plan_path)
except OSError:
    pass
search_options = "lama-first"
cmd = [
    "python3",
    self.planner_path,
    "--alias",
    search_options,
    "--plan-file",
    self.plan_path,
    self.domain_path,
    self.problem_path,
]
subprocess.run(cmd).check_returncode()
with open(self.plan_path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    plan = f.read()
```

Some comments about the code in the question:

- After `subprocess.run(...)`, call `.check_returncode()`, which aborts if the subprocess hasn't exited successfully (with exit code 0, indicating success).
- Don't use `except: pass`. It hides all exceptions, so you won't be notified about relevant errors.
- For simplicity and portability (e.g. to Windows), use *open(...)* + *read()* rather than `cat` to read a file in Python.
- No need to specify `shell=False`, that's the default when *cmd* is a list or tuple.

FYI Because of kernel buffers and caches, data may be flushed to permanent storage (e.g. filesystem on the HDD or SSD) several seconds later. However, you don't have to wait for that in your program, because the kernel will make sure that any subsequent read following a (flushed) file write will see the output of the write, even if the output is only in buffers or caches.

Comment: in some occasions the planner might not find a plan, hence there will be no `plan.txt` file after executing `subprocess.run(cmd).check_returncode()`.

Comment: You can use `if os.path.isfile(self.plan_path):` to detect that, or `except FileError:` around `open`.